# Android app(Marshmallow) crashes while requesting permissions

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I am trying to revoke permissions of my app in my SplashScreen but its been crashing everytime. I have slo put check in my onCreate to check if the sdk version is >= 23.

SplashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

// Splash screen timer
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
MediaPlayer ringtone;
Context context;
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 500;
private Activity activity;
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    context = getApplicationContext();
    activity = this;
    ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
    Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
    System.out.println(isInternetPresent);
    if(isInternetPresent){
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            public void run() {

                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
        boolean granted=checkPermission();
        Log.d("Permission already there","---"+granted );
        /*if(!granted){
            requestPermission();
        }*/
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            System.out.println("Build version is"+Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
            requestPermission();
        }

    }
    else{

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Connected to internet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
        builder.setMessage("No Internet Connection Available. Do you want to try again")  
        .setCancelable(false)  
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, close
                // current activity
                Boolean status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(getApplicationContext());  
                if(status){
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashScreen.class);
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else{
                    // create alert dialog
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {  
                //  Action for 'NO' Button 
                finish();    
            }  
        });  

        //Creating dialog box  
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();  
        //Setting the title manually  
        alert.setTitle("No Internet");  
        alert.show();  

    }
}
private boolean checkPermission(){
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)+
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this, Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS)+
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)+
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this, Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT)+
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this, Manifest.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD)+
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this, Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK)+
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this, Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT)+
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)+
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)+
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this, Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT)+
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE)+
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this, Manifest.permission.VIBRATE)+
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)+
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)+
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashScreen.this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)

            ;
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        System.out.println("Returning true");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Returning false");
        return false;
    }
}
private void requestPermission(){
    Log.d("requestPermission ","Inside requestPermission");
    Log.d("activity ",activity+"");
    Log.d("activity ",Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION+"");
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)&&
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS)&&
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)&&
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT)&&
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD)&&
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK)&&
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT)&&
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)&&
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.CAMERA)&&
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT)&&
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE)&&
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)&&
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)&&
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)&&
            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity,Manifest.permission.VIBRATE)){
        Log.d("requestPermission","Inside if requestPermission");

    } else {
        Log.d("requestPermission","Inside else of requestPermission");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT,
                Manifest.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD,
                Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK,
                Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT,
                Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                Manifest.permission.CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
                Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS,
                Manifest.permission.VIBRATE,
            },PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Snackbar.make(view,"Permission Granted, Now you can access location data.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Permission Granted, Now you can access location data.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            //  Snackbar.make(view,"Permission Denied, You cannot access location data.",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Permission Denied, You cannot access location data.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        break;
    }
}


}
```

In my logs what I can see its printing activity variable and some other variables too. I am not understanding which variable is getting null.
logs.txt

```
10-19 15:25:40.282: I/System.out(15747): Returning false
10-19 15:25:40.282: D/Permission already there(15747): ---false
10-19 15:25:40.282: D/requestPermission(15747): Inside requestPermission
10-19 15:25:40.282: D/AndroidRuntime(15747): Shutting down VM
10-19 15:25:40.293: E/AndroidRuntime(15747): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 15:25:40.293: E/AndroidRuntime(15747): Process: com.example, PID: 15747
10-19 15:25:40.293: E/AndroidRuntime(15747): java.lang.RuntimeException:   Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MainActivity}:   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.app.Activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
10-19 15:25:40.293: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
10-19 15:25:40.293: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
10-19 15:25:40.293: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
10-19 15:25:40.293: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
 10-19 15:25:40.293: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 10-19 15:25:40.293: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 10-19 15:25:40.293: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
 10-19 15:25:40.293: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 10-19 15:25:40.293: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
10-19 15:25:40.293: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
10-19 15:25:40.293: E/AndroidRuntime(15747): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.app.Activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
 10-19 15:25:40.293: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):   at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ActivityCompat23.java:37)
 10-19 15:25:40.293: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):   at android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ActivityCompat.java:363)
 10-19 15:25:40.293: E/AndroidRuntime(15747):   at com.example.MainActivity.requestPermission(MainActivity.java:140)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to not request permissions at the `SplashActivity` start. Request it when `MainActivity` is already started. I think your problem could be that you finish `SplashActivity` before the app will execute all the code relevant to permissions (as you are starting the next activity in the delayed handler).

Comment: Didn't work for me though :/ 
I don't think, splash screen has anything to do with it :)

Comment: @Dennis paste your code using gist or something like that and I will check what could be problem